# How to calculate the grid point precipitation from the station data?

Tags: interpolation

I have a problem to convert my hourly station precipitation data to the surrounding grid points.

I need to convert 4 station hourly rainfall data to `18, 60, and 240 grid points` for `0.0625,0.03125, and 0.015625` respectively.

I know how to do it in ArcGIS.

I have 20 years hourly precipitation data that need to be interpolated to those grid points.

Making 20 years hourly raster data seemed impossible to me to start with.

Comment: What is your goal? What to do with data depends on each information you are trying to generate and what you want to do with it. Please, clarify.